Theoretical model performance
this is a theoretical question that I would like to learn more form. Let's say we have some task and we have four datasets A, B, C and D. Using this data I want to obtain the best neural network for the task. Let's say I use the following two strategies

I train a single neural network on all the datasets combined (A, B, C, and D)
I train a single neural network on each dataset individually. Then, to come to a single conclusion I use a majority vote to make a decision.

Which neural network might perform the best?
I expect that there is no real answer to this, other than 'it depends...'. But I assume that a subject like this must've been research a lot in the last 20 years. Can anyone point me in the right direction in order to find an approximation to my question?
Btw, I know that this might be related to 'boosting', but I have not found something that explores my case.

... It depends. How similar are these datasets? If they are it might be better to pool them together, if they are not then it's probably better to do separate models.
